# connecting signal with method of self in PyQt4

Tags: pyqt

I am having difficulty connecting a signal with a method in PyQt4.
I can connect a bound signal of object A with a method of object B,
but I can't connect a bound signal of object A with a method of self
(object where the connections are made.)
What am I doing wrong?  See below:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class FooA(QObject):
    trigger=pyqtSignal(str)

    def receive_trigger(self,a):
        print'triggered in FooA, string',a

class MainObj(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a1=FooA()
        self.a2=FooA()
        #I can connect signals and methods of separate objects:
        self.a1.trigger.connect(self.a2.receive_trigger)
        self.a1.trigger.emit('hi')
        #... but I can't connect a signal with a method of self
        self.a1.trigger.connect(self.receive_trigger)
        self.a1.trigger.emit('hi')
    def receive_trigger(self,a):
        print 'triggered in MainObj'
```

executes as:
    MainObj()

> triggered in FooA, string hi
>   triggered in FooA, string hi

I expected to see an additional line, > triggered in MainObj

Thanks in advance.
Bill

Comment: Works as expected for me. Are sure the code you've posted is the same as what you're trying to run?

Comment: Confirmed works fine for me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already seem to know, signals must belong to `QObject`s, but this problem is occurring because you are not calling the constructor of `QObject`. `FooA` does not override the constructor, therefore the default constructor is called and the signals work as expected. In `MainObj` however, you do not call the superclass' (`QObject`) constructor, so signals will not work. To fix, either put:

```
QObject.__init__(self)
```

or

```
super(QObject, self).__init__()
```

(based on your conventions) at the top of `MainObj`s contructor, and the signals will then work as expected.

Comment: You are right about not calling the super class init, but were you actually able to reproduce the OPs issue? What version of PyQt4 does this fail to work under?